# Getting "executable chromedriver needs to be available in the path" error while executing the selenium script using pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

1. While trying to execute the below code, I am getting 2 errors.
2. **When executing the same script without pytest, it works fine.**

   **test_home-page.py**

   ```
    class HomePageTest:
     serv_obj = Service('//home//Downloads//chromedriver')
     opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
     opts.add_argument('--headless')
     opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj, options=opts)
    driver.get('site url')
    print(driver.title)
    hp = HomePage(driver)
    def test_logo(self,hp):
     assert hp.get_logo() == 'logo url'
     driver.close()
   ```

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   file "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service. Py", line 70, in start
   cmd. Extend(self. Command_line_args())
   file "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service. Py", line 58, in command_line_args
   **raise notimplementederror("this method needs to be implemented in a sub class")
   notimplementederror: this method needs to be implemented in a sub class**

   **during handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:**

   traceback (most recent call last):
   file "/home/downloads/pycharm-community-2021.3.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner. Py", line 35, in 
   sys. Exit(main(argv=args, module=none, testrunner=unittestpy. Teamcitytestrunner, buffer=not jb_disable_buffering))
   file "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/main. Py", line 100, in **init**
   self. Parseargs(argv)
   file "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/main. Py", line 147, in parseargs
   self. Createtests()
   file "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/main. Py", line 158, in createtests
   self. Test = self. Testloader. Loadtestsfromnames(self. Testnames,
   file "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader. Py", line 220, in loadtestsfromnames
   suites = [self. Loadtestsfromname(name, module) for name in names]
   file "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader. Py", line 220, in 
   suites = [self. Loadtestsfromname(name, module) for name in names]
   file "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader. Py", line 154, in loadtestsfromname
   module = **import**(module_name)
   file "/home/pycharmprojects/project/testcases/test_home_page. Py", line 7, in 
   class homepagetest:
   file "/home/kishore/pycharmprojects/project/testcases/test_home_page. Py", line 14, in homepagetest
   driver = webdriver. Chrome(service=serv_obj, options=opts)
   file "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver. Py", line 70, in **init**
   super(webdriver, self). **init**(desiredcapabilities. Chrome['browsername'], "goog",
   file "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver. Py", line 90, in **init**
   self. Service. Start()
   file "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service. Py", line 93, in start
   raise webdriverexception(
   **selenium. Common. Exceptions. Webdriverexception: message: the executable chromedriver needs to be available in the path.
   This method needs to be implemented in a sub class**

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not clear what issue you are facing. Please share more details about your code, the current output and the expected output.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: "The executable chromedriver needs to be available in the path." This may be the root cause of your problem, probably you haven't put the driver in the path.

Comment: what they mean by "not in path" is that a path to the webdriver was not provided so it falls back to an environment variable that specifies the driver's path.   Either specify the path in your code or set your environment variable to the path of the chromedriver: Environment variable is: "webdriver.chrome.driver"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @medium-dimensional Have added more details. Please check and let me know. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @pcalkins Thanks for your reply. I've already added the driver folder to the PATH and moreover, I am not seeing this error when I am running using just selenium(without pytest).